# Cant Access State from a function

Tags: react-native, state, func

I am trying to alert this.state.name but unfortunately, It shows **cant read property name error**

```
export default class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    Pro: [],
    name:'g',
    phone:'',
    pass:'',

    }}

registerUser(){

alert(this.state.name)}

render(){
return(
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.registerUser} style={styles.buttonContainer}
      onPress={this.registerUser}>})}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
registerUser =()=>{
alert(this.state.name)}
```

and in `<TouchableOpacity>`:

```
onPress={()=>{this.registerUser()}}
```

it will work!